# Unity .Net 2.0 UPNP Port Mapping

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, mono, .net-2.0, upnp

I have recently been trying to setup port mapping for my game. This is to make one of the players be the host. For that I need the player to open port 7777.

If there is a match already on it will simply join it. If it doesn't find empty matches it will simply make one. And If it fails to make one it will wait until someone makes one and join it.

Therefor I need to be able to use something like UPnP to portmap my port. I also need to be able to catch errors to see wheter to proceed with creation of a match or to simply wait for one and join.

I am currently working in the Unity game engine which uses .NET 2.0. This makes me very limited as Open.NAT isn't compatible. I tried Mono.NAT but I can't get it working.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I should approach this? What libraries to use and maybe even provide me with code snippets to get me started.

Thanks, TwoTen.

Edit1: The current Mono.NAT code looks like this:

```
private void DeviceFound(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    INatDevice device = args.Device;
    Debug.Log("2");
    Mapping map = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 6699, 6699);
    Debug.Log("3");
    device.CreatePortMap(map);
    Debug.Log("4");
    int test = device.GetAllMappings().Length;
    Debug.Log(test);
    foreach (Mapping portMap in device.GetAllMappings())
    {
        Debug.Log("5");
        Debug.Log(portMap.ToString());
    }
}
private void DeviceLost(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
{
    INatDevice device = args.Device;
    Mapping map = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 6699, 6699);
    device.DeletePortMap(map);
}
```

I The last debug statement that is called is number 4. I the port does not get opened and no excetion is thrown either.
What am I doing wrong?

Also, In my start function I call this:

```
NatUtility.DeviceFound += DeviceFound;
NatUtility.DeviceLost += DeviceLost;
NatUtility.StartDiscovery();
```

Comment: " I tried Mono.NAT but I can't get it working" Please post the code to that. This works for me. I need to see what you are doing. Also, how do you know that it is not working?

Comment: I updated the post to include my code.

Comment: Repalce `Debug.Log(test);` with `Debug.Log("4++"+test);` then update the question again with the Log. Also, where did you place Mono.NAT DLL?

Comment: My mono.nat dll is in my Asset folder. The Debug.Log("4++" + test) never gets called. Only 1,2,3 and 4 gets called. And currently I am using CanYouSeeMe.org to verify if the port got properly added.

Comment: That seems right. Your code is exactly what I am using. The problem with NAT is start it works on some routers and does not work on others. Sometimes, it doesn't work because of firewall, sometimes it doesn't because UPNP is disabled on your router. Make sure that your Editor does not have Firewall blocking it. Also, if you have access to your router, login and check if UPNP is disabled.

Comment: UPNP is enabled. How would I make sure that my firewall is disabled for the Unity Editor?

Comment: For firewall , try something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFilXQ0GCwQ). You can also test this on another network to make sure that the problem is not your router.... Update me on this. I have one more solution before  I give up.

Comment: Well, Firewall already has a rule to allow UnityEditor. I will attempt a different network later when I get access to it. But other games I personally play uses UPnP and my router supports it without any issues.

Comment: Ok. Before that. Try Open.NAT that has been ported to Unity [here](https://github.com/mcatanzariti/Open.NAT). It says **Open.Nat.Net35.sln**. Open it and build it. Put the DLL in the Asset folder and try it. Please let me know if this works. There is so many Mono.NAT  not working in  Unity on this site and I want to go back and close them.

Comment: Do I use the same code or?

Comment: No. [Here](https://github.com/mcatanzariti/Open.NAT/blob/master/Open.Nat.ConsoleTest/Main.cs) is the test code.Look for the code inside `#if NET35` That you should copy into your Unity Start function and test it. Make sure to replace any `Console.WriteLine` with `Debug.Log`.

Comment: Oops. [Here](https://github.com/mcatanzariti/Open.NAT/blob/master/Open.Nat.Tests/UpnpMockServer.cs) is the test code made for Unity. It has the Start function and everything needed to test it.

Comment: Assets/AutoMatchmaker.cs(159,31): error CS1061: Type `System.IO.FileStream' does not contain a definition for `CopyTo' and no extension method `CopyTo' of type `System.IO.FileStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 That's the error im getting

Comment: Also, That code you sent last. It has a Start function that gets called in Main. It's also made for a console application. It's not for unity. Did you send the wrong one?

Comment: The Main function won't be called. Put `var server = new UpnpMockServer("WANIPConnection:2");` from the Main function to the top of the Start function. As for your error create a Stream extension method and use the code in [this](http://textuploader.com/d5hjr).

Comment: I get this when I add your code. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'int' Backbone.CSharp C:\Users\user\Documents\UnityLogin\Backbone\Assets\AutoMatchmaker.cs 158 Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer on how to successfully. I dropped Mono.NAT and instead went with Open.NAT which has been ported to .NET 3.5 which is compatible with Unity!

The final code I ended up using looks like this:

```
  private static Task Test()
{
    var nat = new NatDiscoverer();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(5000);

    NatDevice device = null;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    IPAddress ip = null;

    return nat.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            device = task.Result;
            return device.GetExternalIPAsync();

        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            ip = task.Result;
            sb.AppendFormat("\nYour IP: {0}", ip);
            return device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 7777, 7777, 0, "myGame Server (TCP)"));
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            return device.CreatePortMapAsync(
                new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, 7777, 7777, 0, "myGame Server (UDP)"));
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\nAdded mapping: {0}:1700 -> 127.0.0.1:1600\n", ip);
            sb.AppendFormat("\n+------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+");
            sb.AppendFormat("\n| PORT | PUBLIC (Reacheable)           | PRIVATE (Your computer)        | Description                        |                         |");
            sb.AppendFormat("\n+------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------+--------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+");
            sb.AppendFormat("\n|      | IP Address           | Port   | IP Address            | Port   |                                    | Expires                 |");
            sb.AppendFormat("\n+------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------+--------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+");
            return device.GetAllMappingsAsync();
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            foreach (var mapping in task.Result)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("\n|  {5} | {0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,-21} | {3,6} | {4,-35}|{6,25}|",
                    ip, mapping.PublicPort, mapping.PrivateIP, mapping.PrivatePort, mapping.Description,
                    mapping.Protocol == Protocol.Tcp ? "TCP" : "UDP", mapping.Expiration.ToLocalTime());
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("\n+------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------+--------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+");
            sb.AppendFormat("\n[Removing TCP mapping] {0}:1700 -> 127.0.0.1:1600", ip);
            return device.DeletePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 1600, 1700));
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\n[Done]");
            Debug.Log(sb.ToString());
        });
}
```

All I had to do was to do this in my start function:

```
Test().Wait();
```

The router registers the port and opens it. HOWEVER. The website canyouseeme.org FAILED to see the port as open for what ever reason. To verify that it was registered I went into my router settings and looked for UPnP. There was then a list of applications including mine. I am yet to do real world tests but I will update the post once those have been made.

The Open.NAT version compatible with Unity was found here:

Edit: I have now performed real world tests. Everything is working and users can connect without relay and or unitys matchmaking servers